# Traveling salesman problem: can a terrible strategy beat a good one?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Until yesterday, I was under the naive impression that constructing a weighted graph where the nearest-neighbour algorithm gives the *worst* possible route, would have the property that any other strategy would be *better*; in particular the furthest-neighbour algorithm. This was of course a mistake: indeed, for $n=4$ or $5$ cities, forcing the nearest-neighbor to produce a *bad* route, one also forces, in parallel, an *equally* bad route for the furthest-neighbour strategy. Things get complicated and fiddly for $n>5$, so I am thinking this is not a good approach, which brings me back to square one:

**Question**

Is it possible to construct a weighted graph such that, given a starting city, choosing the furthest away city at each stage yields a *shorter* route than picking the closest?

Comment: Do you want to still have the property that the nearest-neighbor algorithm gives the worst possible result?  If not, it's easy.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I think the way the question is formulated implies that nearest-neighbor need not be best. The alternative would make an interesting follow-up question. I would like to see your solution to the former.

Comment: Oops, sorry, not so easy.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222637/travelling-salesman-can-the-furthest-neighbour-algorithm-beat-the-nearest-neigh